# Embed dynamically react components in "Component container"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Background**

I have a problem with dynamically embedding components. I'm working on a CMS, which will allow to add random CMS Components, which are written in react.
Each component renders to its own div, all components are completely separated. They do not know about existence of other components. I believe, it is not the "react way" of doing stuff, but this is what I've got in my project, and rewriting everything is not an option.

In general this approach works fine, for example when components are added next to each other, one after another. However, I have few components, which can embed other components. I want to re-use components as much as possible.

I will try to describe an example:
Let say I have a Teaser component, which renders an image, and optionally Editor can add to the Teaser component other components: Text and/or Button.
So in the end the teaser component may only have image, sometimes Image and two buttons, and sometimes Image, Text, and the button.

All components are added by the CMS editor, so when I place Button on a page, it will render a button. When editor will add teaser, it will render itself (with no children components yet).

**What is the problem/question:**

When Editor now adds button to the teaser component I don't know how to handle it properly.

When component is added, it has to be added outside of Teaser Component root div, otherwise Teaser component will remove any embedded components.

What I could do, I could have component registry, and when for example Button is added to the Teaser component, I could pass the Button component JSON params to the teaser component params as for example children array, and Teaser will have a logic to for example based on some property, it will take appropriate component (Button) from the Component Registry, and render it, **however** when component is added to the teaser, as it is completely independent CMS component, it doesn't know that it should be rendered by the teaser component. So what I will have:

1. Button is added, so it will render a button,
2. Teaser will be notified that something has changed, so it will render itself, and the children, so the button will be rendered twiced.
3. The same will happen when rendering a page: Teaser will render itself, then Button will render itself

Any ideas how such case can be solved ?

Comment: A sample of your code would be helpful. Are you asking how to handle buttons added to components that render children (ie `const onClick = () => doSomething...;` and its connected to the component like `<Teaser><button onClick={onClick}>Click me</button></Teaser>`) or how to generate components based on the components parameters? I don't understand what you mean by "Teaser will be notified...".

Comment: If you don't show us a minimal example of your code and how things are working, people won't be able to grasp the problem and provide potential solutions.

Comment: One Quick Question to understand your issue : Did you tried creating button in parent component and passing it to the children component by using props ??

Comment: @SILENT I cannot add the code. I tried to explain as much as possible. I have two react components which can be drag and dropped. One can be embedded into the second one. All of them render to their own div-container. When both of them are on the page, for example one is embedded into first, they will both trigger render, as the embedded component doesn't know if it's embedded or not.